# Определить большую сторону треугольника. Python

Tags: python

В самом задании: Треугольник задан координатами своих вершин. Найти периметр и площадь треугольника. **Определить большую сторону**. Я нашел периметр и площадь треугольника, а как найти его большую сторону?

```
import math

a = int(input("Введите сторону a = "))
b = int(input("Введите сторону b = "))
c = int(input("Введите сторону c = "))
p = (a + b + c) / 2
s = math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c))
perimeter = a+b+c
print("Периметр треугольника = ", perimeter)
print("Площадь треугольника равна: ", s)
```

Comment: говорите заданы координаты, а сами указываете длинну,
несостыково4ка

Comment: `max(a, b, c)`.

Comment: если задаете длину, как сейчас, то - max(a, b, c), если переделаете на координаты, как в задании - предварительно посчитайте длину и снова max

Comment: Вам надо [math.hypot](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подсчета длинны отрезка по двух точках можно использовать функцию [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot). Предположим, что вы уже прочитали все координаты и записали их в массив:

```
import math

coords = [ [0, 0], [2, 2], [2, 0] ]

a = math.hypot(*[i - j for i, j in zip(coords[0], coords[1])])
b = math.hypot(*[i - j for i, j in zip(coords[0], coords[2])])
c = math.hypot(*[i - j for i, j in zip(coords[1], coords[2])])

p = (a + b + c) / 2
s = (p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c)) ** 0.5

print(f'P = {a + b + c}')
print(f'S = {s}')
print(f'Max seg = {max(a, b, c)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас изначально вводятся неверные данные. В задании сказано считать координаты вершин, а Вы просите сразу ввести стороны. Это нужно переделать.
После того, как Вы получите координаты точек, можно будет найти между ними расстояние:

```
ab = sqrt((xb-xa)*(xb-xa) + (yb-ya)*(yb-ya))
```

ab - расстояние между точками a и b, xa и xb - координаты x точек a и b соответственно, ya и yb - координаты y точек a и b соответственно

Так можно найти каждую сторону, потом найти площадь и периметр. После этого можно достаточно просто найти меньшую сторону, есть несколько способов. Например, можно создать создать дополнительную переменную(допустим, d), присвоить ей значение длинны одной из сторон и затем сравнить с двумя другими. Если d будет меньше стороны, с которой сейчас сравниваем, то в d записываем длину стороны, с которой сейчас сравнили

```
//Где-то ранее были посчитаны стороны ab, ac, bca
d = ab
if(d<ac):
    d=ac
if(d<bc):
    d=bc
```

Вариант громоздкий, но так Вам будет проще увидеть логику

Comment: `(xb-xa)*(xb-xa)` - тут лучше использовать возведение в степень `(xb-xa)**2`, потому что любое повторение кода потенциально ведёт к ошибкам рано или поздно, например, когда в одном месте код меняют, а в другом забывают поменять и т.д.